# VB.net Owned form top level order - topmost property

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have **Main form** and 4 owned forms now how I order them?

I want owned `form1` to be at top of **main form** and owned `form2` at top of **mainform** and owned `form1`.

If I click to `form1` then `form1` becomes over `form2`. Thats no good for me.

If I set property of `form2` Topmost = True then it work like charm. But again not good because then it's always allover the screen if I open notepad then this piece of `form2` is at top of the notepad.

Anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: So the owner of Form2 should be Form1, not Main.

Comment: @HansPassant holy... so easy! lol thanks m8, put it as an answer. I though it wont work because form2 is wider than form1 so i didnt even tried this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is to set owner of Form2 to be Form1 as @Hans Passant said in comments.